# Heat Pump and Electrical Emergency Heat on Same Breaker?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I am replacing my current central ducted HVAC and want a heat pump. My preferred option is emergency electrical heat instead of a gas furnace. There is no space in the breaker panel for another 220 V breaker.

Can the heat pump 220 V breaker be used also for the emergency electric heat? They will not both operate at the same time.

Comment: Are you installing minisplits? Or are you putting in a heat pump that will use the central ducted system? Electric resistance heat can use a **LOT** of power, so the rating of the various systems matters - e.g., if your heat pump uses a 30A breaker and your emergency heat uses a 50A breaker then you may or may not be able to use 50A-compatible wire for the heat pump and then that one breaker for both. But while largely independent (you can have breaker space issues without load issues or vice versa), a load calculation is in order before proceeding. **Pictures of your panel would help.**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact `central ducted HVAC` is not a mini split, not even close.  The if and when (30/50) do not apply here

Comment: Heat Pump does not consume extra energy. It resides in the outdoor unit. It has a limited heating capability, so if you live in soutern states it will be enough, but not for northern states.

Comment: @Ruskes OP stated "I am replacing my current central ducted HVAC". That can mean a number of different things. It *can* mean "keep it central ducted but replace the A/C with a heat pump". Or it *can* mean "rip out the ductwork and install minisplits". **We don't know.**

Comment: Can you post photos of your breaker panel please, including any labeling on the inside of the door?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact my heat pump has two breakers, one for the outside unit, one for the inside air handler including emergency heat. I was surprised, I expected three circuits, but the electronics and fan are all on the same 60A breaker as the strips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, modern heat pumps are so wide-ranging that [they no longer need emergency heat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi&index=2).  See 15:50 particularly.  Of course, the old-guard American makers will still cheerfully sell you a 1980s model LOL. In fact the linked video (and its follower) discusses the exasperation of finding modern units from old guard contractors.

Second, if the emergency heat is integrated, you can't count on them not operating at the same time. A few systems use the emergency heat for defrosting.  Check your manual.

Third, and the big problem: Emergency heat is **much bigger**!  It's a huge mismatch as far as breaker sizes.  So "no".

It would be possible to have a subpanel which feeds both the emergency heat and the heat pump.

Now, if you do have gas, and can engineer it in, I would encourage a gas Empire/Williams floor or wall furnace. These are entirely convection powered, and do not use electricity (they self-power a millivolt thermostat, which can be anywhere).  And that means, **they work when the electricity is out**.

Comment: Since OP prefers electric to gas, I'm betting that (like me) they are in the Stop Burning Stuff camp. My house has gas and I absolutely refused to consider gas heat when replacing the 25 year old furnace with a heat pump.

Comment: Not trying to start a battle, @KMJ, but you do realize that most electricity is produced by burning stuff, right? And that which isn't (hydro, wind, solar, nuclear) all have their camps of environmentalists who will argue that each of those methods is worse than the coming of the antichrist. Just something to think about.

Comment: However, from a practical point of view in an area with freezing weather and power outages, purely *backup* gas heat that works when the power is out is low impact on the "burning stuff" front and less hazardous than many a half-posteriored generator hookup. But a gas powered whole-posteriored generator is an option, if you can manage that.

Comment: Sure, but that's changing quickly and equipment has a long lifecycle. A furnace I install now will still be burning stuff in twenty years. An electric heat pump will be using whatever the current mix of generation is, which is rapidly changing. I also have solar panels on the roof which generate about 20% of the electricity right here, which I can't do with gas.

Comment: And yeah, no interest in starting a battle. I just thought an inefficient gravity furnace is a weird recommendation for someone who specifically said they don't want gas.

Comment: @KMJ "Stop Burning Stuff"?  Gee, I wonder where you got that :) :) :) No, the operative word there is **emergency** heat, I'd expect the heat pump to do the daily work. And I'm fine with eviscerating plumbed methane lines from the building and just having a propane inlet manifold that only ever gets pressurized during an emergency, and stoke it with portable tanks. Because here's what's not environmental.  Filling a construction dumpster with drywall, wet insulation, broken pipes, ruined floorboards, and sopped personal possessions because you did not prevent freeze during an outage.

Comment: Power goes out rarely enough here that I own a portable catalytic propane heater that's safe for indoor use. Turns out it's handy other times too.